# Can't connect to AWS EC2 instance from internet

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I created my first EC2 instance (linux) using Amazon Web Services, but I can't connect on any port from any host.  I changed the inbound rules on my security groups to allow connections from any ip `0.0.0.0/0` and any protocol.  But when I telnet on port 22 or port 80 or any other port, the network connection times out with no connection.

What else do I need to configure to connect to my EC2 instance from the internet beside the security group inbound rules?

Comment: This is a real PITA . Thanks for asking: but the answer does not make things more "comfortable".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently all new EC2 instances are created inside a Virtual Private Cloud at Amazon. This means traffic is not routed from the internet to the EC2 host until a few more things are set up.  The things to check are:

- subnet association to the vpc
- existence of an internet gateway on the vpc
- association of the subnet to a routing table
- a new rule in the routing table which routes traffic from the internet to the EC2 host and back

Here is a diagram of this most basic setup from [this article at AWS knowledge base support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html).

[image]

I followed this article doing the steps I listed in the bullet list above, and now I can connect on ssh and any other port allowed in the inbound rules for my EC2 host's security group.

Comment: This is a crazy amount of work for e.g. an ephemeral ec2 instance for a specific task that won't be renewed. Is there really not a shortcut for all this?

Comment: @javadba there is a shortcut for large scale, and it's called scripting.  But unfortunately there is no "quick start" option for one-off newbies.